# How do I send a DM to a user in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, dm

All I'm doing right now is trying to send a dm to myself to see if I can get this working. I've tried:

```js
client.users.cache.get(id).send('hi')
```

But I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')." I suppose this has something to do with myself not being cached, but I'm unsure how to go about caching myself. Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Comment: What is the `id` variable mean here and where do you get it from? Try console logging `id` before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UserManager#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=send). This will create a dm if needed, then send the message

```js
client.users.send(userId, "content")
```